# how add time value delay in js loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, time, delay

```
<ul>
    <li class="wow fadeInRightBig" data-wow-delay="0s">element1</li>
    <li class="wow fadeInRightBig" data-wow-delay=".5s">element2</li>
    <li class="wow fadeInRightBig" data-wow-delay="1s">element3</li>
    <li class="wow fadeInRightBig" data-wow-delay="1.5s">element4</li>
    <li class="wow fadeInRightBig" data-wow-delay="2s">element5</li>
    <li class="wow fadeInRightBig" data-wow-delay="2.5s">element6</li>
    <li class="wow fadeInRightBig" data-wow-delay="3s">element7</li>
</ul>
```

How to using a js loop for add time in data-wow-delay?
I start created this code:

```
$("ul li").attr('data-wow-delay', function(){
    var text = "";
    var number =+ 0.5;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i+=0.5) {
        text += i + number; +"s";
    };
    return text;
});
```

but I do something wrong. I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: You cannot add delay to JS loop. You can use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. If you can explain a little more(like what you are trying to achieve), it would be easier for us to help you

Comment: Could you please tell me , what you want to accomplish  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to accomplish the HTML code you write first?
You can do that with the number variable outside the "loop" and just add 0.5 to it each time.
Your original code also had an error here: `text += i + number; +"s";` there is a `;` in the middle of your assignment.

```
var number = 0.0;
$("ul li").attr('data-wow-delay', function(){
    var text = "";
    number += 0.5;
    text += number +"s";
    console.log(text);
    return text;
});
```

Try: https://jsfiddle.net/jz3b8e10/1/

Comment: @MariuszBrzóska No problem, you can up vote or accept the answer to show other users that it helped you. Glad it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `index()` and then multiple by `0.5` i.e. a number.

```js
$(function() {
  $("ul li").attr('data-wow-delay', function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    var number = 0.5;
    return (index * number) + "s";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="wow fadeInRightBig">element1</li>
  <li class="wow fadeInRightBig">element2</li>
  <li class="wow fadeInRightBig">element3</li>
  <li class="wow fadeInRightBig">element4</li>
  <li class="wow fadeInRightBig">element5</li>
  <li class="wow fadeInRightBig">element6</li>
  <li class="wow fadeInRightBig">element7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not so good it looks because the change is 1 second and it should be half a second

Answer (score 0):

not sure what your function is supposed to do but you could use a recursive function along side with setTimeout

```
$("ul li").attr('data-wow-delay', function(){
    var number =+ 0.5;
    var index = 0;
    addText(number, index);
});

function addText(number, index){
    text += i + number; +"s";
    if(index < 5){
        setTimeout(addText(number, index+=1), 5000)//5 seconds
    }
    return text;
}
```